# Unique filter in Nunjuck

Tags: nunjucks, gitbook

```
systems:
- name: Fred
  country: DE
- name: Wilma
  country: US
- name: Pebbles
  country: DE
- name: Dino
  country: US

---

# Systems 

Countries: {{ page.systems | join(",", "country") }}
```

I am trying to create a GitBook page with a list of items containing no duplicates. I.e I would want to apply a 'unique' filter or 'distinct' filter in my Nunjucks template for the page. The template needs to process the page variables (YAML). The above template generates the output:

```
Countries: DE,US,DE,US
```

I would like it to produce the output

```
Countries: DE,US
```

How could I achive that? (Given that 'unique' filter is not supported with Nunjucks.)

Answer (score 1):

You can extend your Nunjucks through [Custom filter](https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/api.html#custom-filters)

```
const nunjucks = require('nunjucks');
const env = new nunjucks.Environment(/* loaders etc... */);
env.addFilter('unique', arr => arr instanceof Array && arr.filter((e, i, arr) => arr.indexOf(e) == i) || arr);

let out = env.renderString(`{{[1, 2, 3, 2] | unique }}`);
console.log(out);
```